# 960 Grid System nested grid units

Tags: html, css, grid, nested, 960.gs

I'm trying to use nested grids with the 960 grid system, which according to the 960.gs website should work fine if the first child is assigned the alpha class and the last child assigned the omega class. However, I've found that even with these classes, the first child grid appears in the correct position, while any further children appear slightly offset. An example of this can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xXgzK/):

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container_12" style="background:#454545">
        <div class="grid_12" id="wrapper">
            <div class="grid_12 alpha row highlight">
            1
            </div>
            <div class="grid_12 omega row highlight">
            2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*
  960 Grid System ~ Core CSS.
  Learn more ~ http://960.gs/

  Licensed under GPL and MIT.
*/

/*
  Forces backgrounds to span full width,
  even if there is horizontal scrolling.
  Increase this if your layout is wider.

  Note: IE6 works fine without this fix.
*/

body {
  min-width: 960px;
}

/* `Container
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12,
.container_16 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 960px;
}

/* `Grid >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12,
.grid_13,
.grid_14,
.grid_15,
.grid_16 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.push_1, .pull_1,
.push_2, .pull_2,
.push_3, .pull_3,
.push_4, .pull_4,
.push_5, .pull_5,
.push_6, .pull_6,
.push_7, .pull_7,
.push_8, .pull_8,
.push_9, .pull_9,
.push_10, .pull_10,
.push_11, .pull_11,
.push_12, .pull_12,
.push_13, .pull_13,
.push_14, .pull_14,
.push_15, .pull_15 {
  position: relative;
}

.container_12 .grid_3,
.container_16 .grid_4 {
  width: 220px;
}

.container_12 .grid_6,
.container_16 .grid_8 {
  width: 460px;
}

.container_12 .grid_9,
.container_16 .grid_12 {
  width: 700px;
}

.container_12 .grid_12,
.container_16 .grid_16 {
  width: 940px;
}

/* `Grid >> Children (Alpha ~ First, Omega ~ Last)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.alpha {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.omega {
  margin-right: 0;
}

/* `Grid >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .grid_1 {
  width: 60px;
}

.container_12 .grid_2 {
  width: 140px;
}

.container_12 .grid_4 {
  width: 300px;
}

.container_12 .grid_5 {
  width: 380px;
}

.container_12 .grid_7 {
  width: 540px;
}

.container_12 .grid_8 {
  width: 620px;
}

.container_12 .grid_10 {
  width: 780px;
}

.container_12 .grid_11 {
  width: 860px;
}

/* `Grid >> 16 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_16 .grid_1 {
  width: 40px;
}

.container_16 .grid_2 {
  width: 100px;
}

.container_16 .grid_3 {
  width: 160px;
}

.container_16 .grid_5 {
  width: 280px;
}

.container_16 .grid_6 {
  width: 340px;
}

.container_16 .grid_7 {
  width: 400px;
}

.container_16 .grid_9 {
  width: 520px;
}

.container_16 .grid_10 {
  width: 580px;
}

.container_16 .grid_11 {
  width: 640px;
}

.container_16 .grid_13 {
  width: 760px;
}

.container_16 .grid_14 {
  width: 820px;
}

.container_16 .grid_15 {
  width: 880px;
}

/* `Prefix Extra Space >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .prefix_3,
.container_16 .prefix_4 {
  padding-left: 240px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_6,
.container_16 .prefix_8 {
  padding-left: 480px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_9,
.container_16 .prefix_12 {
  padding-left: 720px;
}

/* `Prefix Extra Space >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .prefix_1 {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_2 {
  padding-left: 160px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_4 {
  padding-left: 320px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_5 {
  padding-left: 400px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_7 {
  padding-left: 560px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_8 {
  padding-left: 640px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_10 {
  padding-left: 800px;
}

.container_12 .prefix_11 {
  padding-left: 880px;
}

/* `Prefix Extra Space >> 16 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_16 .prefix_1 {
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_2 {
  padding-left: 120px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_3 {
  padding-left: 180px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_5 {
  padding-left: 300px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_6 {
  padding-left: 360px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_7 {
  padding-left: 420px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_9 {
  padding-left: 540px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_10 {
  padding-left: 600px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_11 {
  padding-left: 660px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_13 {
  padding-left: 780px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_14 {
  padding-left: 840px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_15 {
  padding-left: 900px;
}

/* `Suffix Extra Space >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .suffix_3,
.container_16 .suffix_4 {
  padding-right: 240px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_6,
.container_16 .suffix_8 {
  padding-right: 480px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_9,
.container_16 .suffix_12 {
  padding-right: 720px;
}

/* `Suffix Extra Space >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .suffix_1 {
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_2 {
  padding-right: 160px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_4 {
  padding-right: 320px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_5 {
  padding-right: 400px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_7 {
  padding-right: 560px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_8 {
  padding-right: 640px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_10 {
  padding-right: 800px;
}

.container_12 .suffix_11 {
  padding-right: 880px;
}

/* `Suffix Extra Space >> 16 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_16 .suffix_1 {
  padding-right: 60px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_2 {
  padding-right: 120px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_3 {
  padding-right: 180px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_5 {
  padding-right: 300px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_6 {
  padding-right: 360px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_7 {
  padding-right: 420px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_9 {
  padding-right: 540px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_10 {
  padding-right: 600px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_11 {
  padding-right: 660px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_13 {
  padding-right: 780px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_14 {
  padding-right: 840px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_15 {
  padding-right: 900px;
}

/* `Push Space >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .push_3,
.container_16 .push_4 {
  left: 240px;
}

.container_12 .push_6,
.container_16 .push_8 {
  left: 480px;
}

.container_12 .push_9,
.container_16 .push_12 {
  left: 720px;
}

/* `Push Space >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .push_1 {
  left: 80px;
}

.container_12 .push_2 {
  left: 160px;
}

.container_12 .push_4 {
  left: 320px;
}

.container_12 .push_5 {
  left: 400px;
}

.container_12 .push_7 {
  left: 560px;
}

.container_12 .push_8 {
  left: 640px;
}

.container_12 .push_10 {
  left: 800px;
}

.container_12 .push_11 {
  left: 880px;
}

/* `Push Space >> 16 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_16 .push_1 {
  left: 60px;
}

.container_16 .push_2 {
  left: 120px;
}

.container_16 .push_3 {
  left: 180px;
}

.container_16 .push_5 {
  left: 300px;
}

.container_16 .push_6 {
  left: 360px;
}

.container_16 .push_7 {
  left: 420px;
}

.container_16 .push_9 {
  left: 540px;
}

.container_16 .push_10 {
  left: 600px;
}

.container_16 .push_11 {
  left: 660px;
}

.container_16 .push_13 {
  left: 780px;
}

.container_16 .push_14 {
  left: 840px;
}

.container_16 .push_15 {
  left: 900px;
}

/* `Pull Space >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .pull_3,
.container_16 .pull_4 {
  left: -240px;
}

.container_12 .pull_6,
.container_16 .pull_8 {
  left: -480px;
}

.container_12 .pull_9,
.container_16 .pull_12 {
  left: -720px;
}

/* `Pull Space >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .pull_1 {
  left: -80px;
}

.container_12 .pull_2 {
  left: -160px;
}

.container_12 .pull_4 {
  left: -320px;
}

.container_12 .pull_5 {
  left: -400px;
}

.container_12 .pull_7 {
  left: -560px;
}

.container_12 .pull_8 {
  left: -640px;
}

.container_12 .pull_10 {
  left: -800px;
}

.container_12 .pull_11 {
  left: -880px;
}

/* `Pull Space >> 16 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_16 .pull_1 {
  left: -60px;
}

.container_16 .pull_2 {
  left: -120px;
}

.container_16 .pull_3 {
  left: -180px;
}

.container_16 .pull_5 {
  left: -300px;
}

.container_16 .pull_6 {
  left: -360px;
}

.container_16 .pull_7 {
  left: -420px;
}

.container_16 .pull_9 {
  left: -540px;
}

.container_16 .pull_10 {
  left: -600px;
}

.container_16 .pull_11 {
  left: -660px;
}

.container_16 .pull_13 {
  left: -780px;
}

.container_16 .pull_14 {
  left: -840px;
}

.container_16 .pull_15 {
  left: -900px;
}

/* `Clear Floated Elements
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* http://sonspring.com/journal/clearing-floats */

.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.container_12:before,
.container_12:after,
.container_16:before,
.container_16:after {
  content: '.';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.clearfix:after,
.container_12:after,
.container_16:after {
  clear: both;
}

/*
  The following zoom:1 rule is specifically for IE6 + IE7.
  Move to separate stylesheet if invalid CSS is a problem.
*/

.clearfix,
.container_12,
.container_16 {
  zoom: 1;
}    

html,body {
        margin:0;
    }

    #wrapper {

    }

    .row {
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }

    .highlight {
        background:yellow;
    }
```

Does anyone have a fix to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are misusing `grid_12` where you should use `container_12` in the wrapper.

Moreover alpha and omega classes are designed for aligned cells, that means that two `grid_12` divs cannot be aligned inside a container_12 div (that would be 24 columns, and this does not fit)

Lastly, as I understood, it seems that you want to turn that into two aligned `grid_6` div

Hope this helps !

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for clearing this up. So alpha/omega are not needed for stacking grids on top of one another?

Comment: @Noobatron : to stack grids, you would add an empty `<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>` between two containers. Take a sharp look at the demo source code here : http://960.gs/demo.html